# javascript: how to refer to an anonymous function within the function itself?

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function, scoping

if arguments.callee is not allowed in "use strict", and we can't do

```
var f = function g() {
    //g
}
```

because in IE that wouldn't work (or that would work "weirdly") http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs, then what other options do we have to refer to the anonymous function within the function itself?

Comment: This is not an anonymous function. anonymous functions don't have a handle (like `f` in your case)

Comment: @nEEbz: It's the `g` that makes it not anonymous. The function in an expression `var f = function() {}`` is anonymous.

Answer (score 5):

That's *precisely* what the [Y combinator](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/93526/) is for.

[Here's an article by James Coglan about deriving the Y combinator in JavaScript.](http://Blog.JCoglan.Com/2008/01/10/deriving-the-y-combinator/)

Comment: The Y combinator seems like overkill here.

Comment: @Matt Ball: it's a generic solution to this problem that not only works for JavaScript but for *any* language. @jamietre's solution, for example, looks basically like an idiomatic JavaScript implementation of the Y combinator with some inlining applied. I doubt you can come up with such a trick yourself if you've never heard of the Y combinator.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a named function expression. Just declare and initialize it the normal way.

```
function f() {
    f();
}
```

The only viable alternative with ES5 strict is to use the code in your question, and deal with IE's crappy NFE implementation. But: do you really expect a browser that gets NFEs so horribly wrong (ahem, IE) to implement `"use strict"` anytime soon?

Comment: @Matt Ball i may have been mistaken, but i remember reading that function declarations (the normal way) is not allowed in ES5 strict unless it is within the "global" scope..

Comment: @Pacerier `[citation needed]`

Comment: @MattBall iE10 beta has use strict in it. It's beaten chrome/safari.

Comment: @Pacerier: [this MDC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#Strict_mode_for_functions) makes me think you're remembering incorrectly.

Comment: @Raynos did IE10 fixed this issue?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't know. I assume that named function expressions work in IE9 if they don't I'm going to get really angry.

Comment: @Pacerier: function declarations are allowed in global or function code, but not within blocks.

Comment: @Tim which makes perfect sense _anyway_, since JS only has global and function scopes, not block scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather convoluted way to do it, but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/4KKFN/4/

```
var f = function() {
    function f() {
        if (confirm('Keep going?')) {
            this.apply(this);
        }
    }
    f.apply(f);
}

f();
```

Comment: Can't say I'd actually use something like this in real code, but seems like a legit workaround...

Comment: Having now just read about "the Y combinator" (first I've ever heard of it) I realize, this is actually much the same thing.